# Finding similarities in a dictionary

Tags: python

I'm trying to find similarities between multiple .txt files. I've put all these files in a dictionary with the name of the file as key.

Current code:

```
import pandas as pd
from os import listdir, chdir, getcwd
path = (r'C:\...path')
chdir(path)
files = [f for f in listdir(path)]
files_dict = {}

for filename in files:
    if filename.lower().endswith(('.txt')):
        files_dict[str(filename)] = pd.read_csv(filename).to_dict('split')

for key, value in files_dict.items():
    print(key + str(value) +'\n')
```

Key in this case is the filename. The value are the headers and the data. 
I want to find out if there are duplicates in the values between multiple files so I can join them in SQL. I'm not sure how to do this

Edit example files:

```
timestamp,Name,Description,Default Column Layout,Analysis View Name
00000000B42852FA,ADM_EIG,Administratief eigenaar,ADM_EIG,ADM_EIG
000000005880959E,OPZ,Opzeggingen,STANDAARD,
```

And from the code:

```
Acc_ Schedule Name.txt{'index': [0, 1], 'columns': ['timestamp', 'Name', 'Description', 'Default Column Layout', 'Analysis View Name'], 'data': [['00000000B42852FA', 'ADM_EIG', 'Administratief eigenaar', 'ADM_EIG', 'ADM_EIG'], ['000000005880959E', 'OPZ', 'Opzeggingen', 'STANDAARD', nan]]}
```

Edit 2: Suggested code

```
for key, value in files_dict.items():
    data = value['data']
    counter = Counter([item for sublist in data for item in sublist])
    print([value for value, count in counter.items()])
```

Output: `['00000000B99BD831', 5050, 'CK102', '0,00000000000000000000', 'Thuiswonend', 0, '00000000B99BD832', ........`

Comment: Can you provide an example of such files ?

Comment: I've edited the post

Comment: What are you looking for duplicates in? The column names?

Comment: Is there any restrictions on libraries? For example, is it convenient for you to use pandas?

Comment: I'm looking for duplicates (similarities) between the data, not the column names.

Comment: No restrictions on libraries. Thought pandas would be useful since it's ~580 .txt files

Comment: Dos your example contain a duplicate: the repeated ADM_EIG in one item, or not duplicates, since the two rows differ?

Comment: @doctorlove It contains duplicates on the same row yes. I'm looking for duplicates between files so I can join them in SQL (so primary / foreign keys)

Answer (score 0):

The `Counter` counts the frequencies of items, so will tell you anything that appears more than once. Pull out the `data` from your dictionary:

```
from Collections import Counter

data = [
   ['00000000B42852FA', 'ADM_EIG', 'Administratiefeigenaar', 'ADM_EIG', 'ADM_EIG'],
   ['000000005880959E', 'OPZ', 'Opzeggingen', 'STANDAARD', nan]
]
```

You need to flatten the list of lists:

```
[item for sublist in data for item in sublist]
```

The Counter will give you a frequency for each item:

```
>>> Counter([item for sublist in data for item in sublist])
Counter({'ADM_EIG': 3, '00000000B42852FA': 1, 'Administratief eigenaar': 1, '000000005880959E': 1, 'OPZ': 1, 'Opzeggingen': 1, 'STANDAARD': 1, nan: 1})
```

which you can then filter for what you need:

```
counter = Counter([item for sublist in data for item in sublist])
[value for value, count in counter.items() if count > 1]
```

which gives `['ADM_EIG']`

---

*Edit  to match the question edit*

To look at all the rows, grab all the data and look for duplicates:

```
data = []
for key, value in files_dict.items():
    data.extend(value['data'])

counter = Counter([item for sublist in data for item in sublist])
print([value for value, count in counter.items() if count > 1])
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I make this work with my code? All the values and headers are in the same dictionary at this time (files_dict) I also want the name of the text files in which there are similar values

Comment: I think `data = value['data']` in your for loop - you may need to flatten all of it as you go.

Comment: I've edited the post with your code. Could you check that for me please. I don't think it gives the correct output

Comment: The `if count > 1` will tell you duplicated (non-unique) items. I suspect you want to build up the data from all the rows.

Comment: I don't follow?

Answer (score 0):

If all the columns are the same in all files, I suppose you can ues `pd.duplicated()` following way:

```
import pathlib
import pandas as pd


def read_txt_files(dir_path):
    df_list = []
    for filename in pathlib.Path(dir_path).glob('*.txt'):
        # print(filename)
        df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=0)
        df['filename'] = filename  # just to save filename as an optional key
        df_list.append(df)

    return pd.concat(df_list)

df = read_txt_files(r'C:\...path')  # probably you should change path in this line     
df.set_index('filename', append=True, inplace=True)
print(df)
                                Name              Description  ...
timestamp        filename                                       
00000000B42852FA first.txt   ADM_EIG  Administratief eigenaar  ...
000000005880959E first.txt       OPZ              Opzeggingen  ... 
00000000B42852FA second.txt  ADM_EIG  Administratief eigenaar  ... 
000000005880959K second.txt      XYZ              Opzeggingen  ...
```

So you can get index with duplicated data:

```
df.duplicated(keep='first')

Out:
timestamp         filename  
00000000B42852FA  first.txt     False
000000005880959E  first.txt     False
00000000B42852FA  second.txt     True
000000005880959K  second.txt    False
dtype: bool
```

And use it, for instance, to filter the data:

```
df[~df.duplicated(keep='first')]

Out:
                                Name              Description  ...
timestamp        filename                                       
00000000B42852FA first.txt   ADM_EIG  Administratief eigenaar  ...  
000000005880959E first.txt       OPZ              Opzeggingen  ... 
000000005880959K second.txt      XYZ              Opzeggingen  ...
```

**Edit:** example with different columns in different files but the same scheme. 
first.txt:

```
timestamp,Name,Descr,Column Layout,Analysis View Name
00000000B42852FA,ADM_EIG,Administratief eigenaar,ADM_EIG,ADM_EIG
000000005880959E,OPZ,Opzeggingen,STANDAARD,
```

second.txt:

```
timestamp,Descr,Default Column Layout,Analysis View Name
00000000B42852FA,Administratief,ADM_EIG,ADM_EIG
000000005880959K,Opzeggingen,STANDAARD,
```

third.txt

```
timestamp,Descr,Default Column Layout,Analysis View Name
00000000B42852FA,Administratief eigenaar,ADM_EIG,ADM_EIG
000000005880959K,Opzeggingen,STANDAARD,
```

last lines of second.txt and third.txt are duplicated.

Apply same code:

```
...
print(df)

Out:  # partial because it's to wide
                            Analysis View Name Column Layout  ...
timestamp        filename                                      
00000000B42852FA first.txt             ADM_EIG       ADM_EIG  ... 
000000005880959E first.txt                 NaN     STANDAARD  ... 
00000000B42852FA second.txt            ADM_EIG           NaN  ... 
000000005880959K second.txt                NaN           NaN  ... 
00000000B42852FA third.txt             ADM_EIG           NaN  ... 
000000005880959K third.txt                 NaN           NaN  ...
```

Missing values (if no such column in .txt) are filled with NaN's.
Locating duplicated colums:

```
df.duplicated(keep='first')

Out:
timestamp         filename  
00000000B42852FA  first.txt     False
000000005880959E  first.txt     False
00000000B42852FA  second.txt    False
000000005880959K  second.txt    False
00000000B42852FA  third.txt     False
000000005880959K  third.txt      True
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately not all column names are the same. Can it work with different column names?

Comment: @Frankicks are there the same number of columns or not?

Comment: NB: this solution will work properly if all values of the same kind are stored in columns with a same names. If not all columns names are the same for the same kind of data in different files, it might be difficult unless same columns in different files are located at the same positions

Comment: I would guess that the column names I'm looking for are the same, because there are multiple columns names with 'Primary key' for example. But there are different columns between multiple files

Comment: @Frankicks i've just extended my answer and add an example of code's output if files contains different columns, hope it helps